# unable to keep pagination track

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

Pagination links are shown correctly for 1st time, but when I click 2nd page link the data vanishes.

Here is my code:

## Controller

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator');
    var $paginate = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'limit' => 5
        )
    );
    public function index() {
        //debug("in index");
        //$this->render();
        $d=$this->data['lower_limit'];
        //debug(" df ");
        //debug($d);
        $lower= $this->data['lower_limit'];
        $upper= $this->data['upper_limit'];

        $conditions = array('Post.post_id >=' => $lower, 'Post.post_id <=' => $upper);
        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;

        $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Post', $conditions);

        $this->set('data', $data);
        $this->set('lower_limit',$lower);
        $this->set('upper_limit', $upper);

    }
}
```

## Model

I have not overridden paginate and pagination count methods.

Comment: when you go to 2nd page $this->data no longer contains information. You have to store those informations in session or pass data via GET instead of POST

Comment: can u give me some example to store data for later use @arilia

Comment: It should work as you have it.  What's the path the page links are going to?  They should have something like `index/2` or `index?pg=2` (this should happen automatically)

Comment: Address bar shows _posts/index/page:2_, but no data is displayed @Dave

Comment: What version of Cake? (always include that in your questions)

Comment: You just have to start debugging.  Use `debug()` to find out 1) whehter it's getting to the action 2) what data is returned in the $data array each time, 3) look at the book for what the page links should be..etc

Comment: cake 1.3. i'm using [link](debug()) as well first time it shows correct pagination when i click 2 page link it flushes from $data @Dave

Comment: thanks @Dave i have corrected the mistake using debug().